rsync transport filter rules are not behaving as expected
I am trying to figure out some details about rsync behaviour and filter rules. My file with rules, .transport.rsync is like this:
+ /*
+ /d1/***
+ /d2/***
- /***

and the rsync is run this way:
rsync -rlptDuzE \
      --itemize-changes \
      --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 \
      --delete \
      --exclude-from=.transport.rsync \
      /home/me/ /mnt/a1/a11/

The structure of /home/me is
d1
d2
d3
d4
f1.txt
f2.dat

and the idea is to copy all files in /home/me (that is fN.*) and the directories d1 and d2 and anything they might contain to /mnt/a1/a11/ but nothing else.
As per the man, /* should stop at slash. But for some reason it is not working and the whole /home/me/ gets copied. Why?
Sub-quesion 1: Does it matter if I have include/exclude filters in a file if I specify it via --exclude-from or --include-from
Sub-question 2: with the setup above, i keep getting logged ".L..t......" or ".d..t......", or even better "*deleting" a file which is not deleted from target (as it should not be since it is the same in the source and target). What are those strange updates (I know the meaning of the flags that it is trying to set Link time to the trasnfer time but why?).

What are these /dN directories? How are they relevant? You don't seem to be trying to copy those, you are only copying from inside /home/me. Is your "file with rules" the .transport-out-ssd.rsync you are using? And what is the directory structure? Can you please simplify this to a toy example that reproduces the problem so we can try locally?

@terdon I have updated the question as per your suggestions. /dN are directories contained in /home/me, the file with rules is /home/me/.transport.rsync. I have added simple directory structure. All directories dN can have some content (other directories or files).

If your filter rules start with + or -, it does not matter if you include them with --exclude-from or --include-from. The manual explains this (see the detailed description of these options).

You say that "the whole /home/me/ gets copied", but you don't say what this means.  Does it mean that /home/me/otherdir/otherfile also gets copied? As for why the time on links and directories are synced, you asked for it (with -t).

The problem seems to be the contradictory + /* (include all directories) and - /*** (exclude everything under any directory). I admit I would have expected the last one to overwrite the first, but that doesn't seem to be happening. What you want is:
+ /d1/***
+ /d2/***
- */
+ *

This will include directories d1 and d2 and all their contents, exclude all other directories, and include all files.
I am testing in this directory:
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo

$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 6 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 12:12 bar
drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 12:12 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon   30 Jul 23 12:13 .transport.rsync


$ ls -l bar/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d2
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d3
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f2.dat

If .transport.rsync has the contents shown above, and I run this command, I get the expected output:
$ rsync -rlptDuzE       \
  --itemize-changes \
  --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 \
  --delete \
  --exclude-from=.transport.rsync \
  /home/terdon/foo/bar/ /home/terdon/foo/baz/
.d..t...... ./
>f+++++++++ f1.txt
>f+++++++++ f2.dat
cd+++++++++ d1/
cd+++++++++ d2/
>f+++++++++ d2/file.d2

$ ls -lA baz
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon   30 Jul 23 12:11 .transport.rsync

I don't really know the details of how it works, this was found by trial and error. However, it is clear that the order of exclusions is important. For example, reversing the last two lines to make the file like this:
+ /d1/***
+ /d2/***
+ *
- */

results in everything being copied:
$ rmr baz/*; rsync -rlptDuzE \
  --itemize-changes \
  --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 \
  --delete \
  --exclude-from=.transport.rsync \
  /home/terdon/foo/bar/ /home/terdon/foo/baz/
.d..t...... ./
>f+++++++++ f1.txt
>f+++++++++ f2.dat
cd+++++++++ d1/
cd+++++++++ d2/
>f+++++++++ d2/file.d2
cd+++++++++ d3/
cd+++++++++ d4/

$  ls -lA baz
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d2
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d3
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jul 23 11:02 d4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jul 23 11:03 f2.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon   30 Jul 23 12:11 .transport.rsync

As for sub-question 1, no it doesn't matter, the manual explains that if the rule starts with a - or +, then it is explicitly set as an exclude or include rule respectively. It is only if the rules do not start with either character that they will be treated as exclude/include depending on the option used (from man rsync):

--exclude-from=FILE
[...]
If  a  line begins with "- " (dash, space) or "+ " (plus, space), then the type of rule is being explicitly specified as an exclude or an include (respectively).  Any rules without such a prefix are taken to be an exclude.

No idea about sub-question 2, sorry. I suggest you post it as a separate question.
